# Innovation Projects vs. Innovative Projects? What's the difference?

Tags: synonyms

It seems to be that **innovation projects** refer to those projects that are going to innovate current systems or practices with newer things, or generally speaking, bringing something newer to replace existing ones within a given scope. For example, upgrade from 3G network to 4G network, or from 2G to 3G. The process is bringing something newer, but they may be not "new" globally (in the world).

However, **innovative projects** mean the projects that want to bring something new (creative) to this world. For example, develop a 5G or 6G network, which has not yet even on the planet.

Do I understand right?

Answer (score 1):

My take on these phrases is one of aspiration versus declaration. An "innovative project" has, in fact, produced an innovation.

Conversely, an "innovation project" merely hopes to produce an innovation, but it might not have happened yet.

As always, the borders of these words are smeared by hyperbolic usages, such as describing a project as being innovative because is has a goal to be innovative. So, take this with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound quite right.

Innovation projects, yes, I think your explanation is good.  The project produces innovation as a result.

Innovative projects means that the project is innovative, not necessarily the results.  Using new methods to create something.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the meaning of the two terms, they actually refer to the development of something new, which didn't exist or is significantly different from what existed before.  The process you refer to in your definition of 'innovation process' is more an 'upgrade process' or an 'update process'.

[Innovation](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/innovation.html):

> - **The process of translating an idea or invention into a good or service that creates value or for which customers will pay**. Innovation involves deliberate application of information, imagination and initiative in deriving greater or different values from resources, and includes all processes by which new ideas are generated and converted into useful products.

[Innovative](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/innovative.html) :

> - the quality of an idea which is new and different.
> - characterized by, tending to, or introducing innovations.

Source: (businessdictionary)

Comment: so you mean there is no difference between innovation projects and innovative projects?

Comment: I think that they both suggest the development of something new. The upgrade or update of existing technologies are not innovations unless they refer to new significant developments.

Answer (score -2):

innovation : converting idea into goods and service to buy customers and ather hand innovative means creativity and brain storming

Comment: You'll have to answer considering the words as a combination. As in **innovation projects** instead of just **projects**.